# Subclassing Room Entities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Is there a way to subclass entities in Room?

I have an car `entity`

```
@Entity(tableName = "cars")
data class Car(
        @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "vin") val vin: String,
        val manufacturer: String,
        val model: String,
        val color: String,
        val modelYear: Int,
        val trim: String = ""
) {

    override fun toString() = String.format("%s %s %s %s", modelYear, manufacturer, model, trim)
}
```

But I want to move the `manufacturer`, `model`, and `modelYear` to a `Vehicle` entity and have the `Car` inherit from it.

I tried creating a `Vehicle` entity with those fields and use `data class Car : Vehicle`, but does not compile. The error is `This type is final and cannot be inherited`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `kotlin`, all classes are final by default.

From [Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance)

> The open annotation on a class is the opposite of Java's final: it
>   allows others to inherit from this class. `By default, all classes in`
>   `Kotlin are final`, which corresponds to Effective Java, 3rd Edition,
>   Item 19: Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it.

so you need to add `open` keyword  so use

```
open class Vehicle(..){...}
```

then

```
data class Car(...): Vehicle(..){}
```

Side Note: if you trying to inherit `data` classes then simply you cannot inherit `data` class in Kotlin because method like `copy` in data class are final which cannot be overridden by the child class (which in this case is `data` class so it will do it automatically) and it's hard to implement other methods like `equals` when class hierarchy grows exponentially with different data members though you can avoid all this collision by making non-data parent class or `abstract` class

Comment: interesting side note. I just read the same thing in another SO post. I guess I could use an `abstract`, but it isn't providing the same benefits I was hoping for. Is there a reasoning in why it's designed like this or just a Kotlin limitation?

Comment: yeah for abstract , it's just a `Is-a` relationship and for data class inheritance , one reason is copy method overriding is not possible other is equals is not possible, see example `data class Vehicle(val model:String);  data class FutureCar(val engine:FancyEngine,val body:BodyBuilderFactory,val model:String):Vehcile(model);` so in this case it's hard to implement equals by default respected to other child of `Vehicle` class though overriding is allowed but the spec designer thought it might break the purpose of having data class and add more implications